# Can I create multiple twitter accounts all connected to one e-mail address?

Tags: twitter

I'd like to create other twitter accounts, but the only way I see for this is to also create separate e-mail addresses for each twitter account, which is tiresome. Is there a way to work around creating multiple e-mail addresses ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a gmail account, you can append +XXXX with XXXX being whatever you want and it will go to the same email address.

For example, you could have an email address like mymainaddress@gmail.com and then register accounts as mymainaddress+twitter1@gmail.com, mymainaddress+twitter2@gmail.com, etc

Emails to all three of those addresses will show up in the inbox for  mymainaddress@gmail.com

I personally use this for website registration so I can track who gives my email to spammers.

The only thing I don't know if there's anything in Twitter's registration algorithm that would prevent this

Comment: Didn't work with yahoo mail. Still nice to know for gmail. Thanks.